# NSDataDetector: what does it parse?

Tags: cocoa, nsregularexpression, nsdatadetector

Is the gamut of expressions that NSDataDetector can parse documented?

We know that NSDataDetector can interpret lots of expressions, such as "Monday evening." And it’s understandable that the *NSDataDetector Class Reference* doesn't want to cover these in detail, since that would likely require frequent documentation revisions.

Still, it would be good to know what’s recognized and what isn’t, especially with an eye to extending the class.

---

(I suspect that [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) is mistaken in thinking that NSDataDetector relies on Cocoa’s linguistic analysis APIs; if it did, would NSDataDetector be a subclass of NSRegularExpression?  Though I admit inheriting from NSRegularExpression seems odd, and might be a code smell.)

Comment: As far as its use of `NSRegularExpression` I'm sure that helps with parsing more normal things like phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

The list of what NSDataDetector recognizes is not documented since it is very complex (it supports thousands of expressions and dozens of languages). This class is also not designed to be subclassable. Have you filed a bug with Apple with the expressions that are missing in your case?

Comment: It's not so much a question of "expressions that are missing," but rather knowing what is covered by data detectors and what we should handle ourselves.

Comment: It's not precisely defined, but it's basically (time-wise since you were mentioning Monday evening) all the times and dates that are precise enough to create an useful event, not too ambiguous (because they try to avoid false positives) and that are not noise (e.g. a Mail "on xxxx at yyy zzz wrote") in about two dozen languages.